# Prove that totally bounded metric spaces are separable

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, solution-verification

> Prove that a totally bounded metric space $M$ is separable.

Please help me complete my proof, I think I'm almost there.

---

Since $M$ is totally bounded, for every $1/n$, there exists a finite set $D_n$ for which $$M \subset \bigcup_{x\in D_n} B\left(x,\frac{1}{n}\right)$$
Let $$D = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty D_n$$
Since all $D_n$ are finite, $D$ is countable. Showing that $D$ is also dense will complete the proof. We know that $D\subset M$ is dense iff $\overline D = M$. So we must show $\overline D \supset M$. In other words, $x\in M\implies x\in \overline D$. We also know that $x\in\overline D$ iff $\forall\epsilon >0$, $B(x,\epsilon)\cap D\ne \varnothing$.

Suppose $x\in M$. For a contradiction, assume that there exists some $\epsilon > 0$ such that $B(x,\epsilon) \cap D = \varnothing$. I'm unable to find a contradiction from here, and would appreciate any help! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose $n$ such that $\frac  1n <\epsilon$. Then $x \in B(d,\frac  1n)$ for some $d \in D_n \subseteq D$. This implies that $d \in B(x,\epsilon) \cap D$ so $B(x,\epsilon) \cap D$ is not empty.

Comment: Could you explain why $x\in B(d,1/n)$ for some $d\in D_n$?

Comment: @epsilon-emperor That is because $x \in M \subseteq \bigcup_{y \in D_n} B(y,\frac  1n)$

Comment: Thank you, that helps! What was your motivation behind the first step, i.e. $1/n < \epsilon$?

Comment: @epsilon-emperor We already know that there is a point of $D$ within distance $\frac  1n$ of $x$. So to get a  point of $D$.within distance $\epsilon$ of $x$ what is requires is $\frac 1 n<\epsilon$